# Linear mixed models: heterogeneity of independent variables-when to transform?

Tags: multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, continuous-data, weights

So Zuur et al (2009) state that to validate a linear mixed model:

-the residuals of the model have to be normally distributed

-the plot: "residuals of the model vs each explanatory variable" have to be homogeneous.

In the case of a continuous explanatory variable that shows a pattern when we plot the residuals against it, would it be thorough to transform this variable?

The authors also state that transformation is, in theory, not necessary since we can add "weights" in the model to inform it of these deviances... When we do that, does that mean we do not have to run a bartlett test or interpret the plot "residuals vs. IV"?

Comment: The remark about weights implies the transformation will be applied to the *response*.  In light of this, the claim that transformation is "in theory not necessary" misunderstands the different effects of transformations and weights--and is generally incorrect.

Comment: I thought the "weights" function and transformation were two very different things. To validate homogeneity of variances, the residuals of the model have to be plotted against the explanatory variables (or Bartlett test). To make it simple, if the different levels of  an explanatory show heterogeneity,  should we transform the explanatory variable or add the "weights" argument?

Comment: Transforming the *explanatory* variable has no direct or universal effect on the variances of the residuals.  What to do and in what order is not something that can be adequately explained in a comment or even a brief post.  For an introduction to *some* of the methods--it does not even go into weighted least squares--you can read my account at http://www.quantdec.com/misc/MAT8406/Meeting07/Diagnostic_Plots.pdf.